# Как правильно указать условие?

Tags: c#

Как правильно указать условие ? Имеется вот такое условие

```
else if(0 < funcX < 3)
```

но Visual Studio ругается

> код CS0019: Оператор < невозможно применить к операнду типа bool и int

Comment: `abs(funcX/1.5-1)<1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> else if(0 < funcX < 3)
> ```

```
else if(0 < funcX && funcX < 3)
```